# Trigger For prevent inserting data According to a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

i need a trigger that prevent some data from inserting in table According to a condition , before inserting any row in the table like this code

```
create Trigger trigger_name 
on table_name
for insert
AS
Begin
if (true)
    insert into table_name values ()
End
```

Comment: Please don't post identical questions to multiple sites in the network. This was [also posted to Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87041/trigger-for-prevent-inserting-data).

Comment: Also: What have you tried? And you need to give more details, such as whether this condition needs to be evaluated per row. A lot of people have the mistaken assumption that a trigger fires per row, when in reality it fires per statement - and a statement can affect multiple rows. So do you want to insert the rows that meet the condition, and discard the rows that don't? Or check the condition and insert all rows if it is true and no rows if it is not?

Answer (score 1):

`Instead of Trigger` (using INSTEAD OF CLAUSE)

> This type of trigger fires before SQL Server starts the execution of
>   the action that fired it. This is differ from the AFTER trigger, which
>   fires after the action that caused it to fire. We can have an INSTEAD
>   OF insert/update/delete trigger on a table that successfully executed
>   but does not include the actual insert/update/delete to the table.

**Syntax:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_nameON {table|view} 
[WITH ENCRYPTION|EXECUTE AS] 
{FOR|AFTER|INSTEAD OF} 
{[CREATE|ALTER|DROP|INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE ]} 
[NOT FOR REPLICATION] 
AS sql_statement [1...n ]
```

Trigger should something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name 
ON table_name 
instead OF INSERT 
AS 
    BEGIN 
        IF (true) 
            INSERT INTO table_name VALUES () 
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`Instead Of Insert trigger`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx) and [**`exists`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) operator to validate the rows that meet the condition

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
ON table_name
Instead OF INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO table_name
      SELECT *
      FROM   inserted
      WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     WHERE  condtion = true)
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using check constraints instead of triggers ?
This is their intended purpose.  Applying simple conditions for preventing inserting/updating data that does not fit your business logic.

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/check.php