# Why the trigger is not inserting new values to the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this trigger that checks the insert statement conditions. It shows the right message, but it doesn't add the values (although it shows the msg "successfully added"). Does anyone know were the problem is?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_SentMessage_Insteadof
ON messages
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT inserted.*
                FROM inserted 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN matchs AS m ON (inserted.sentFrom = m.userID1 
                                                AND inserted.sentTo = m.userID2)
                                            OR (inserted.sentFrom = m.userID2 
                                                AND inserted.sentTo = m.userID1)
                WHERE (m.interesting1 = 0 AND m.interesting2 = 0)))
         PRINT 'Succesfully added' 
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        PRINT 'You can't do that!'  
    END
END
```

For example, when I run:

```
insert into messages values('2017-05-01', 'how are you', '426564774', '201827364')
```

should return "Successfully added", and add it to table, but it only shows the message.

Comment: If you declare an instead of trigger you need to do the insert. Doesn't need to be an `instead of` trigger anyway. And your left join is an inner join because of the `where`.

Comment: i kind of need the condition in the where clause :\ , but what do you meen that i don't need   instead of  ? how can i check the values inserted if they are what i need?

Comment: You want 'after insert'. Happens after the insert, but before the the insert is done. With `instead of` What is done in the trigger is done _instead of_ what the triggering statement was going to do.

Comment: Also, SQL Server triggers are multi-row. Your condition will be satisfied if at least one row meets the criteria. It will take ALL rows failing the if statement to fall through to the else.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually inserting any values. The `INSTEAD OF INSERT`prevents the insert from happening so you have to insert them yourself before the print statement after you have checked the condition. 
Something like 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27659693/6715484

Comment: you mean i should add the    `Insert into messages values('','','','')` after the if statement? because it doesn't work either